# How to set when waypoints triggers

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-waypoints

I am trying to figure out how I can trigger a waypoints function. Right now this function starts when my `info` div is at the very top of the screen. Ideally, I want this to start when the user's bottom of the screen just gets to the `info-box` section. I am unsure of how I can even modify when the event triggers.

Also, for some reason the info-boxes aren't transitions to the right like I am attempting. They just transition into a fade with now horizontal movement. What is wrong with what I am trying?

```js
var $info_show = $('#info');

$info_show.waypoint(function () {
  $('.info-box').addClass("fadeShow");
});
```

```css
#info {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 300px 20%;
}
.info-box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 50px;
  background: #00f;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 100px;
  transition: 1s;
  opacity: 0;
}
.info-box.fadeShow {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(150px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/prefixfree.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="info">
  <div class="info-box">Red</div>
  <div class="info-box">Blue</div>
  <div class="info-box">Green</div>
</div>
```